# Expected number of transactions in a day

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

The number of withdrawals a bank processes in a day follows a random variable X. The number of deposits in a day is represented by $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have the following moment generating functions

$$\displaystyle {M}_{X}(t)=\frac{p}{1-q{e}^{t}}$$
$$\displaystyle {M}_{Y}(t)={\left(\frac{p}{1-q{e}^{t}}\right)}^{r}$$
$q = 1 - p$

What is the expected number of transactions in a day?

Would I multiply these two together and then take the derivative and make all t's = $0$? I am a little shaky on Moment Generating Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$$

You just have to compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ separately.

Alternatively, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, mgf of the independent sum is the product of mgf,  you can also do what you suggested.

Comment: So If I compute them separately I just take the derivatives and set $t=0$? When I do this, it is rather messy and I end up with $${qrp^r\over (1-q)^{r+1}}+{qp\over (1-q)^2}$$ so I end up with $${qr+q}\over p$$ but this isn't an answer.

Comment: I lied, it is an answer.